# Intermediate value property implies continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $g\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function with the intermediate value property.

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose to each sequence $ (x_n) $ converging to $x$ there exists a constant $K$ such that
$$|g(x) - g(x_n)| ≤K \sup _{m}|g(x_n) - g(x_m)|$$
Then show that $g$ is continuous at $x$.

What i have done so far is :

Given $(x_n)\rightarrow x$ and $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n\in (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ for all $n\geq N$..

As $g$ has this intermediate value property, $g$ maps intervals to intervals..

So, $g(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)=M$ an interval in $\mathbb{R}$.. I want to write $M$ as $(g(x-\epsilon),g(x+\epsilon))$

See that $g(x_n)\in M$ for all $n\geq N$ we can assume length of $M$ to be $r>0$

Then, $\sup _{n,m}|g(x_n) - g(x_m)|\leq \max\{r,|g(x_n)-g(x_i)|:1\leq i\leq n\}=L$

So, $|g(x)-g(x_n)|\leq L$.. I some how missed that epsilon...

Help me to clear this,,

Comment: Your question's title is a little misleading: the derivative function of any differentiable function always fulfills the I.V. property (Darboux Theorem) yet it can be non-continuous.

Comment: The subscripts on $\sup$ really confuses me, if $n$ is supposed to be fixed then it shouldn't be in the subscript

Comment: @user160738. Ditto for me.

Comment: @user254665 : i have changed it...

Comment: @user160738 : I have chnaged it...

Comment: Why don't you try contradiction?

Comment: @user64066 : I do not know where to start

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose for a contradiction, the claim is false. This implies for some $\varepsilon_0$ we can find $x_n\in(x-1/n,x+1/n)=I_n$ but $\mid g(x_n)-g(x)\mid\geq \varepsilon_0$. From here, by using intermediate value, you can find another sequence $t_n\in I_n$ such that $g(t_n)=f(x)+\varepsilon_0$ or $g(t_n)=f(x)-\varepsilon_0$. This implies however $g$ takes one of this values infinitely many often, which contradicts with given condition i.e., $t_n\to x$ so there exists $K$ that satisfies given inequality.

Comment: I  just solved it but you beat me by an hour.+1.